# Adding Item To Cart

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am fairly new to React Native and Redux. I am creating a mock shoe store, and I'm having an issue pushing my items to my shopping cart. I've been going over my code for a while now. I want my items to appear in cart screen, however when I press my button, nothing happens.

Here is what I have so far for redux store and my details screen:

```
 import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Button, List } from 'react-native-paper'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { cartActions } from '../../redux/cart.redux';
import { AppCard } from '../AppCard/AppCard';
import { AppScreen } from './AppScreen';

const DetailsScreen = ({route}) => {
    const {product} = route.params

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const addToCart = () => {
        dispatch(cartActions.addtoCart(product))
    }


    return (
        <AppScreen>
            <ScrollView>
            <View>
                <AppCard
                style={style.card}
                imgContainer={style.imgContainer}
                title={product.title}
                price={product.price}
                image={product.image}
                items={product} />
            </View>
            <View style={style.btnContainer}>
                <Button icon="shopping" color="#263238" onPress={addToCart} mode="contained" style={style.btn}>Add To WizCart</Button>
            </View>
            <List.Section title={`${product.title} Details`}>
                <List.Accordion
                title="Product Information"
                left={() => <List.Icon icon="information"/>}>
                <List.Item description={product.description} />
                </List.Accordion>
                <List.Accordion
                title="Ratings"
                left={() => <List.Icon icon="star"/>}>
                <List.Item title="5/5" />
                </List.Accordion>
            </List.Section>
            </ScrollView>
        </AppScreen>
    )
}

export default DetailsScreen

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        backgroundColor: '#263238',
        width: '100%',
        marginHorizontal: 0,
        borderRadius: 5
    },
    imgContainer: {
        height:330
    },
    btnContainer: {
        padding: 10
    },
    btn: {
        padding: 10
    }
});



    import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    totalPrice: 0,
    totalQuantity: 0
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState,
    reducers : {
        addtoCart (state, action){
            // product added to the cart
            const newItem = action.payload
            // check if product is in cart
            const exists = state.items.find(p => p.id === newItem.id)
            // increment cart quantity first
            state.totalQuantity++
            // if statement if it doesn't exist, add

            if(!exists){
                state.items.push({
                    ...newItem,
                    qty:1,
                    totalAmount: newItem.price
                })
                // update total price
                state.totalPrice = newItem.price

            }
            else {
                // increment qty the existing products in cart
                exists.qty++
                state.totalPrice = state.totalPrice += newItem.price
                exists.totalAmount = exists.totalAmount * exists.qty
            }
        },
        removeItem (state, action) {
            const itemToRemove = action.payload

            // check if item's in cart

            const itemExists = state.items.find(p => p.id === itemToRemove.id)
            // remove item if it's 1
            if(itemExists.qty === 1){
                state.items = state.items.filter(item => item.id != itemToRemove.id)
                state.totalPrice = state.totalPrice - itemToRemove.price
            }
            // decrement the qty
            else{
                itemExists.qty--
                itemExists.totalAmount = itemExists.totalAmount - itemToRemove.price
                state.totalPrice = state.totalPrice - itemExists.price
            }

        }
    }
});

export const cartActions = cartSlice.actions;


    import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { cartSlice } from './cart.redux'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        cart: cartSlice.reducer
    }
})


import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { AppScreen } from './AppScreen';
import { CartItems } from '../cartItems.js/CartItems';

const CartScreen = () => {

    const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart.items)

    return (
        <View style={style.container}>
            <AppScreen style={{flex:1}}>
                <FlatList
                data={cart}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                renderItem={(item) => <CartItems items={item} />}
                />
            </AppScreen>
        </View>
    )
}

export default CartScreen

const style = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: can you do a console.log to check if the data is being updated in store?

Answer (score 0):

Update some code as follows:

```
const addToCart = product => dispatch({ type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: product })
```

When you are calling that function addToCart call as follows:

```
 <Button icon="shopping" color="#263238" onPress={() => {addToCart(product)}} mode="contained" style={style.btn}>Add To WizCart</Button>
```

you can visit this repository for more info  :
https://github.com/Hetali21/ReduxDemo

Comment: product is being passed in route params, don't need to pass it as argument in addToCart function.

Comment: Thank You, I appreciate it! I was able to get it working.

Comment: @Sam you can upvote the answer if its useful to you